# logstash unable to connect to Elastic search host

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration

I am getting the below error, after enabling the firewall on the logstash server.

I opened the port 5044 & 9200 on both the elasticsearch and logstash server.

Elasticsearch server is up and running and port 9200 is enabled.

[2022-05-04T05:12:25,182][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@prcs-ppr-xxx.xxx.local:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@prcs-ppr-xxx.xxx.local:9200/

9200 port on Logstash server is in SYNC_SENT status. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: You're using a site-local address in Logstash but ES might not be listening on that interface. Can you check your network configuration: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

Comment: actually its http://elastic:xxxxxx@prcs-ppr-xxx.xxx.local:9200/